# Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols Android

Tags: android, react-native

[![][1]][1]

Execution failed for task ':app:stripDebugDebugSymbols'.
NDK at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle did not have a source.properties file
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e4JK.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

you can completely remove ndk - as it is not required in latest flutter

this solution worked for me https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12440#issuecomment-601214647

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android

1. Go to local.properties
2. Add this line

ndk.dir=/Users/neerajpawar/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle

and Sync the project

Hope it works